# Como é o correto ao declarar uma variável que seja um ponteiro?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, estilo-de-codificação, declaração-de-variável

Vejo que há quem faça

```
int* variavel;
```

E há quem faça

```
int *variavel;
```

Qual é o correto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usado desta forma ambos estão corretos e são aceitos. O ideal é escolher uma forma e adotá-la sempre igual. Vejamos:

```
int* variavel;
```

Quem escolher essa opção quer deixar claro que o tipo é um `int*`, ou dizendo de outra forma, um ponteiro para inteiro. Deixa o nome da variável isolado. Eu normalmente indicaria mais essa, mas ela tem problema em uma situação específica de declaração.

```
int *variavel;
```

Dá na mesma mas parece que o tipo é `int` e a variável é um ponteiro. É confuso. Mas por coerência essa forma é ideal a não ser que você nunca declare mais de uma variável no mesmo *statement*.

O que está declarando aqui?

```
int* var1, var2;
```

Se disse que está declarando duas variáveis do tipo "ponteiro para inteiro", errou. Está declarando `var1` como "ponteiro para inteiro", mas var2 é apenas um inteiro. É esquisito? É. Mas a linguagem é assim. O correto seria:

```
int* var1, *var2;
```

Agora, não fica esquisito o ponteiro perto do tipo escalar? Coerentemente ficaria:

```
int *var1, *var2;
```

Ainda que ambos funcionem.

Algumas pessoas pregam que o bom mesmo é deixar o ponteiro sempre perto do tipo e nunca usar mais de uma declaração no mesmo *statement*, assim:

```
int* var1;
int* var2;
```

Se C tivesse optado por outra forma para indicar ponteiro seria mais fácil, poderia ser algo assim:

```
^int var1, var2;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Declaration.c).

Isso seria lido ponteiro para inteiro e tudo o que está nesse *statement* é deste tipo, se deseja declarar um `int`, deveria ser em outro *statement*. É mais intuitivo, mas a linguagem não foi por esse caminho.

Comment: Eu diria que é uma questão de habituar.